# How to batch find and replace multiple text in multiple documents at once

Tags: regex, batch-file, replace

I have 100 html pages with various text to translate. I have also the translated text ready on a word document. So what I have to do is find multiple blocks of different text and replace them with multiple blocks of the translated text. I use normally dreamweaver which has a good find/replace function but it can only replace 1 block of text/code at a time. More specifically as an example, say i have 3 sentences (I personally have far more, something like 1000 different sentences to be replaced):

ENGLISH TEXT1, ENGLISH TEXT2 and ENGLISH TEXT3.

and want to replace all 3 of them respectively at once with:

SPANISH TEXT1, SPANISH TEXT2 and SPANISH TEXT3.

I need to find the "english blocks of text" wherever they may be in the html documents and replace them with the "spanish blocks of text" all at once without having to repeat the find/replace process thousands of times.

I hope the question is clear enough. I need a free utility for MAC or either someone to explain me exactly how i can achieve this in dreamweaver or elsewhere using Regular Expressions (which unfortunately I don't know anything about).

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Thanks but that program can only find and replace one text at a time. I need to find and replace thousands of different text at once.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [this program](http://search-and-replace.en.softonic.com/mac). it works great, you just choose a folder and then it searches everything in it.

Comment: make sure to double click the "find" button or whatever its called, because it doesn't work for me on a single click.